# Как включить только определенные feature в google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Загружаю geoJson

```
map.data.loadGeoJson(geoJsonPath);
```

Дальше прохожу и отключаю определенные feature

```
map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
if(...){
  map.data.remove(feature);
  }
});
```

Но у меня подгружаются сразу 1000 feature, а включить надо 15. 
Можно ли загружая geoJson указывать чтобы по умолчанию все feature были отключены, а затем включить только некоторые? И как их потом включать после того как я их удалил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загружайте данные запросом, а затем по условию добавляйте только нужные  с помощью метода `addGeoJson`, например, так:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(geoJson) {
    geoJson.features.forEach(function(feature) {
        if (...) {
            map.data.addGeoJson(feature);
        }
    });
});
```